# How can I make my select all check box ignore disabled items?

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript  to allow users to check all items in a form.  However it is checking items even if they are disabled.  Is there a way to make this only work on check boxes that are enabled?

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#selectall').on('click', function () {
            $('.lv').prop('checked', isChecked('selectall'));
        });
    });
    function isChecked(checkboxId) {
        var id = '#' + checkboxId;
        return $(id).is(":checked");
    }
    function resetSelectAll() {
        // if all check box are selected, check the selectall checkbox
        // and vice versa
        if ($(".lv").length == $(".lv:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }

        if ($(".lv:checked").length > 0) {
            $('#edit').attr("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $('#edit').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using a function to check if your checkbox is checked if you can do it like `$('.lv').prop('checked',$(this).is(':checked'));`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [:disabled](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selectors:

```
$(".lv:not(:disabled)").prop("checked", isChecked("selectall"));
```